# Must inequalities face the same way?

Tags: inequality

If I write down $1<x>0$ is that wrong? Must the inequalities face the same way? I think that $1<x>0$ simplifies to $x>1$ but desmos and other software just breaks down and wont deal with any inequalities which do not go the same way.

Comment: It's not wrong, just a bit ugly :) You are correct that is the same as $x>1$.

Comment: First of all, $<$ is a binary relation, so in theory, you shouldn't, formally, write $0<x<1.$ In practice, we do, because it is easy and commonly needed and  relatively unambiguous. But we never write $0<x>1.$ That is hardly ever necessary, and when it is, we usually write it as $x>0,1.$

Comment: I guess its better to write mine as $x>1$ and then $x>0$ then it follows that the first case also covers the second one.

Comment: Multiple inequalities with one side in common $a>b$, $a>c$, also get written $a>b, c$, and people understand. You can often see things like $x_1,x_2,x_3>0$, for example.

Comment: So, basically, abuse of notation depends on unambiguity, the ease that it improves communication, whether there are alternatives, and the frequency we're going to need to use it. Here, you can argue for unambiguous, maybe, but I think it fails the others.

Comment: In particular, the use of $<$ and $>$ obscures that the relation of $0$ and $1$ to $x$ are the same.

Comment: Conclusion: Its not wrong but should be avoided?

Comment: Depends on the definition of "wrong." $x<y<z$ is, technically, wrong, but allowed by custom. $x<y>z$ is technically wrong, and not allowed by custom. There is no consistency requirement for abuse of notation - it is more like spoken language than mathematical language. There is no sense in which $x<y>z$ is "right."

Comment: It is better to write $y>x$ and $y>z$ then. (Then compare $x$ with $z$ to simplify)

Comment: Or $y>\max\{x,z\}$ is another option. By the way, the reason that custom allows $x<y<z$ even though $<$ is a binary relation is because that binary relation is *transitive*, so that $x<y$ and $y<z$ together imply $x<z$ and the whole visible expression is consistent.

Comment: yeah ! thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inequalities face the same way, they are very clear. However, when you write for example $1<x>0<2$ or $x>4<y<5>3<z$, the readers *will* have a hard time understanding. Not writing inequalities the same way is not standard notation, so most of your readers will not understand what you mean anyway. However, you are free to invent your own idiosyncratic notation.